# Align the text of material card title to right

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, mat-card

I try to align my title of matcard to right but the css doesn't work .. why ?

```
<mat-card [ngStyle]="{ 'margin':'5px','height':'130px'}">
  <mat-card-header>

   <mat-card-title [ngStyle]="{ 'text-align':'right' }">BLABLA</mat-card-title>

  </mat-card-header>

</mat-card>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
<mat-card>
    <mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-title class="title-card-left">Test left</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-title class="title-card-right">Test right</mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content></mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

Then define some styles for these classes in your css/scss:

```
.title-card-right{
  display: inline;
  float: right;
}

.title-card-left{
  display: inline;
}
```

and then inside your styles.css

```
.mat-card-header-text{
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can jus use this

```
<mat-card style="height:100px;width:300px;display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;">
   <mat-card-content><span>Contents</span></mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

**[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/centered-mat-card-obgcmr?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: in that case you need to change

Comment: your actual question is center